# How do I return one exact property of an object in powershell (Azure)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

im trying to make an array of Service Principals application ids thats display name all begins with the same prefix

Example:

```
Get-AzAdServicePrincipal -DisplayNameBeginswith "ecp-"

ServicePrincipalNames : {xxxx-75xx71-xxx-xxxx-xxx}
ApplicationId         : xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93x85-xxxxxxxxx
ObjectType            : ServicePrincipal
DisplayName           : ecp-test-1
Id                    : xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
Type                  :
```

i want it to output just the application id field

```
Get-AzAdServicePrincipal -DisplayNameBeginswith "ecp-"

ApplicationId         : xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93x85-xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Select-Object` command, commonly abbreviated to just `Select` to specify which properties to return.

In your case:

```
Get-AzAdServicePrincipal -DisplayNameBeginswith "ecp-" | Select ApplicationId

ApplicationId
-------------
xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93x85-xxxxxxxxx
```

You can commit this to a variable like so.

```
$myAzPrincipleAppId = Get-AzAdServicePrincipal -DisplayNameBeginswith "ecp-" | Select ApplicationId
```

This is a PowerShell object, with one property, `ApplicationId`.  Commonly, you'll need to just get the property without the property name, called dereferencing.  To do that, just use this syntax.

```
Write-host "Our AzPrincipleAppId is $($myAzPrincipleAppId.ApplicationId)"
>
Our AzPrincipleAppId is xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93x85-xxxxxxxxx
```

You can also just pass it in anywhere as `$myAzPrincipleAppId.ApplicationId`